# How are Fees Charged at Kraken?

Tags: exchanges, api, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, exchange-fees

**How are fees charged when I initiate a trade?**

Are they subtracted from my order's volume? Are the fees applied separately from my account's balance? Can I set the currency I want my fees to be charged in?

I have provided the Answer below, including the information given in a support ticket I sent to Kraken Support.

Answer (score 6):

**How are fees charged?**

They are charged in the currency fee set during a trade.

> Due to a discreet nature of trade matching process, it's rather tricky to give a definite answer on how each individual fee is applied. However, a good rule of thumb is to choose a fee currency when placing an order, as this is the one in which fee will be subtracted.

**Are the fees applied separately from my account's balance? Or are they included in trade costs?**

Usually the former is the case - but the latter can occur under certain circumstances:

> Normally, fees are NOT included in a trade and are subtracted from the remaining account balance.
>
> However, if you quote your order in a chosen fee currency (for example, you Buy 500 EUR worth of XBT in XBT/EUR pair), then fee will be included in an order*.

*This means: if your account's balance is 500€, you'll be able to buy bitcoins worth 500€ minus transaction fees.

**Can I set the currency I want my fees to be charged in? Can I choose to be always charged in a single Currency?**

Yes to the first, no to the second.

> Fees can be chosen to get applied in either quote or base currency. So if you're trading LTC/XBT, then it's either XBT or LTC. If, however, you're trading XBT/USD, it's either XBT or USD.

All quotes taken from the Kraken Support Ticket.

Cheers!